# Change the value of a variable in two targets in Ant

Tags: ant

I have one target:

```
<target name="add_inner_class" >
    <property name="client.jar.classes"
              value="${client.class.jar.package.list}"/>
    <foreach list="${client.class.jar.package.list}"
             target="add_inner_class_list" param="outer_class"
             delimiter=" " inheritall="true" />
</target>
```

This target calls a second target `"add_inner_class_list"`.

In the second target I want to update the property defined in calling target (i.e. the property named `client.jar.classes`).
In each call I want this value to persist and be updated if required.

I wondered, can I do this in Ant?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't do that, because Ant [properties are immutable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).  Once a property has a value, it can't be changed.  Quoting from the docs:

> Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for
>   the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.

There are though a couple of things that you might be able to use to achieve what you want.
First is the Ant [`<local>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html), which allows you to have an instance of a property local to a target with a different value to that outside the target.  But looking at the specifics of your question, it appears you want a variable rather than a property - you want the value to be changed at will.  As you are already using ant-contrib, why not use a [`<var>`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)?  Ant-contrib variables are mutable and, in most cases, can just be used straight-forwardly in place of Ant properties.